# Identify and replace data of a column by +1 and -1

Tags: r, xts

I have a one-column xts object:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,4,1,1)
date <- Sys.Date()-20:1
data <- xts(a,date)
colnames(data) <- "a"
data
```

Here I want all the numbers in the column a to be replaced by +1 and then -1 respectively, except 0. I want the `a` column to look like:

```
1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1
```

I've asked similar questions, but this is not a exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is named `df`. This will repeat values 1 and -1 for all `a` that are not 0.

```
df[a!=0,]<-c(1,-1)
```

Comment: i knew it, i'll be very simple. I'm new to r so didn't know this. Thanx